# $\{\sqrt[3]{x}| x\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $\{x\in \mathbb{Q}|\sqrt[3]{x} \}$, what is the difference?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider two following sets:
$$A = \{\sqrt[3]{x}\mid x\in \mathbb{Q}\}$$
$$B = \{x\in \mathbb{Q}\mid \sqrt[3]{x} \}$$

What is the difference between the two sets?

Comment: The second is pure nonsense: what follows `|` must be a *property*.

Comment: The second is like a sentence fragment. You're saying that the set consists of "all rational $x$ such that the cube root of $x$" which is meaningless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one $A = \{\sqrt[3]{x}\mid x\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is perfectly valid as the axiom scheme of extensionality allows it to be a set. (Since $A\subset\mathbb{R}$)

On the other hand, $B = \{x\in \mathbb{Q}\mid \sqrt[3]{x} \}
$ this means nothing, beacuse: What does it mean for some $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ to have the property $ \sqrt[3]{x}$? Nothing, for it is not a property, it is neither true or false.